mention then insert HTML to editor
i am using ckeditor, how can i mention a product and insert HTML information related to that product (including photo and name) instead of just @productname, i mean insert a snippet of html code that i can customize, or any editor which can perform the same operation
function MentionCustomization(editor) {
  editor.conversion.for("upcast").elementToAttribute({
    view: {
      name: "a",
      key: "data-mention",
      classes: "mention",
      attributes: {
        href: true,
        "data-user-id": true,
      },
    },
    model: {
      key: "mention",
      value: (viewItem) => {
        const mentionAttribute = editor.plugins
          .get("Mention")
          .toMentionAttribute(viewItem, {
           
            link: viewItem.getAttribute("href"),
            userId: viewItem.getAttribute("data-user-id"),
          });

        return mentionAttribute;
      },
    },
    converterPriority: "high",
  });

  editor.conversion.for("downcast").attributeToElement({
    model: "mention",
    view: (modelAttributeValue, { writer }) => {
      if (!modelAttributeValue) {
        return;
      }
      return writer.createAttributeElement(
        "a",
        {
          class: "mention",
          "data-mention": modelAttributeValue.id,
          "data-user-id": modelAttributeValue.userId,
          href: modelAttributeValue.link,
          target: "_blank",
        },
        {
          priority: 20,
          id: modelAttributeValue.uid,
        }
      );
    },
    converterPriority: "high",
  });
}

i am adding this MentionCustomization to config plugins, in downcast i can only convert to "a" tag, every attempt when I create a container as a div tag to wrap the img and span doesn't work.
Thanks for help !!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

CKEditor’s Mention feature is primarily designed to insert inline content (e.g., hyperlinks or text spans) rather than complex HTML structures like div tags with nested elements.
function MentionCustomization(editor) {
editor.conversion.for("upcast").elementToElement({
view: {
  name: "div",
  classes: "product-mention",
},
model: (viewElement, { writer }) => {
  const productName = viewElement.getChild(1).data;
  const productId = viewElement.getAttribute("data-product-id");
  const productImage = viewElement.getAttribute("data-product-image");

    return writer.createElement("productMention", {
      name: productName,
      id: productId,
    image: productImage,
    });
    },
   converterPriority: "high",
 });
 editor.conversion.for("downcast").elementToElement({
model: "productMention",
view: (modelItem, { writer }) => {
  const productName = modelItem.getAttribute("name");
  const productId = modelItem.getAttribute("id");
  const productImage = modelItem.getAttribute("image");

  // Create the wrapper div
  const container = writer.createContainerElement("div", {
    class: "product-mention",
    "data-product-id": productId,
    "data-product-image": productImage,
  });

  // Add the image element
  const imageElement = writer.createEmptyElement("img", {
    src: productImage,
    alt: productName,
    class: "product-image",
  });
  writer.insert(writer.createPositionAt(container, 0), imageElement);

  // Add the span element for the name
  const nameElement = writer.createText(productName);
  writer.insert(writer.createPositionAt(container, "end"), nameElement);

    return container;
  },
  converterPriority: "high",
});

// Add the schema for the custom mention type
 editor.model.schema.register("productMention", {
   allowWhere: "$block",
  allowAttributes: ["name", "id", "image"],
  isObject: true,
 });

}
